# Error in catalina log failed to scan postgresql-jdbc.jar, invalid END header

Tags: postgresql, maven, tomcat

I have an error in catalina log :

> AVERTISSEMENT: Failed to scan [file:/usr/share/java/postgresql-jdbc.jar] from classloader hierarchy 
>           java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid END header (bad central directory offset)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:215)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:145)
>           at java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:154)
>           at java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:91)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.(URLJarFile.java:93)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:69)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:99)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:89)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.FileUrlJar.(FileUrlJar.java:41)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:34)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig$FragmentJarScannerCallback.scan(ContextConfig.java:2615)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:258)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:220)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1871)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1259)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:876)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:374)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5355)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1247)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1898)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I copy postgresql-9.2-1004.jdbc41.jar in /usr/share/java following an error in ginco.log :

> Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.postgresql.Driver'
>
> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/postgresql/Driver : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

I do a link on /usr/share/apache-tomcat-6.0.47/ :

> lib -> /usr/share/java/tomcat

In /usr/share/java/tomcat/ i  have :

> -rw-r--r--. 1 tomcat tomcat  579874 26 oct.  12:17 postgresql-9.2-1004.jdbc41.jar
>
> lrwxrwxrwx. 1 tomcat tomcat      35 18 oct.  10:17 postgresql-jdbc.jar -> /usr/share/java/postgresql-jdbc.jar

and in /usr/share/java i have :

> -rw-r--r--. 1 tomcat tomcat  579866 25 oct.  11:28 postgresql-9.2-1004.jdbc41.jar
>
> lrwxrwxrwx. 1 tomcat tomcat      19 17 oct.  18:12 postgresql-jdbc2ee.jar -> postgresql-jdbc.jar
>
> lrwxrwxrwx. 1 tomcat tomcat      19 17 oct.  18:12 postgresql-jdbc2.jar -> postgresql-jdbc.jar
>
> lrwxrwxrwx. 1 tomcat tomcat      19 17 oct.  18:12 postgresql-jdbc3.jar -> postgresql-jdbc.jar
>
> -rw-r--r--. 1 tomcat tomcat  579866 26 oct.  12:34 postgresql-jdbc.jar
>
> -rw-r--r--. 1 tomcat tomcat  515140 25 oct.  11:30 postgresql-jdbc.jar_sav

I copy postgresql-9.2-1004.jdbc41.jar towards postgresql-jdbc.jar

My version of java :

`java -version`

> java version "1.7.0_111"
>
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.6.7.2.el7_2-x86_64 u111-b01)
>
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.111-b01, mixed mode)

I use maven and i configure pom.xml as :

```
<postgresql.jdbc.version>9.2-1004.jdbc41</postgresql.jdbc.version>
```

Comment: I install postgresql-9.2-1004.jdbc4.jar instead of postgresql-9.2-1004.jdbc41.jar and modify pom.xml :

Comment: I install postgresql-9.2-1004.jdbc4.jar instead of postgresql-9.2-1004.jdbc41.jar , copy postgresql-9.2-1004.jdbc4.jar towards  /usr/share/java/postgresql-jdbc.jar and modify pom.xml :  <postgresql.jdbc.version>9.2-1004.jdbc4</postgresql.jdbc.version> and dependency.